# asynchronous http request in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http, mixpanel

```
 require 'net/http'

urls = [
  {'link' => 'http://www.google.com/'},
  {'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/'},
 {'link' => 'http://www.yahoo.com/'}
]

urls.each do |u|
  u['content'] = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse(u['link']) )
end

print urls
```

This will work as procedural code.. I just want to hit a server, no issues about the order. How can i do that in ruby. One option is using threads.

Here's an example using threads.

```
require 'net/http'

urls = [
  {'link' => 'http://www.google.com/'},
  {'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/'},
  {'link' => 'http://www.yahoo.com/'}
]

urls.each do |u|
  Thread.new do
    u['content'] = Net::HTTP.get( URI.parse(u['link']) )
    puts "Successfully requested #{u['link']}"

    if urls.all? {|u| u.has_key?("content") }
      puts "Fetched all urls!"
      exit
    end
  end
end
```

Any better solution..??

PS:- i want to hit mixpanel, so that's why I just want to make a http call and dont wait for the response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lightweight Async handling is the job of Threads (as you said) or [Fibers](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Fiber.html).

Otherwise, you should consider [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) which is a very powerful tool.

EDIT: The above URL for Event Machine is dead. Here is their GitHub account, https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine . It serves as a good starting point.

Comment: rails, question is tagged with rails 3:)

Comment: RIP EventMachine (at least the posted URL)

Answer (score 12):

Here is a [great article](http://www.igvita.com/2009/05/13/fibers-cooperative-scheduling-in-ruby/) covering the topic.

Generally, viable alternatives to using threads for this would be the use of a [Fiber](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Fiber.html) or you could use [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request/wiki/Issuing-Requests). In the latter example you could leave out the callback handling for your particular purpose.

Comment: It's misleading to say that fibers are an alternative to threads. Fibers will not give you concurrency.

Comment: @pguardiario - Fibers absolutely will give you concurrency ... on any IO-bound task.  You are correct that for CPU-bound tasks, you want multiple threads, but when most people are concerned about "concurrency" it's usually for parallel network requests with only minimal processing in between.

Answer (score 2):

If its just about plain http requests in async style, probably [Unirest](http://unirest.io/ruby.html) is the best fit to achieve it.

**Asnc request is as simple as:**

```
response = Unirest.post "http://httpbin.org/post", 
                    headers:{ "Accept" => "application/json" }, 
                    parameters:{ :age => 23, :foo => "bar" } {|response|
response.code # Status code
response.headers # Response headers
response.body # Parsed body
response.raw_body # Unparsed body
}
```