# Rails non-blocking post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, asynchronous, eventmachine

I need to POST to another server rather frequently in my Rails app, but it takes foreeever. The catch is that I don't need the response. Is there any way to speed things up by sending the request and then dropping the connection without waiting for a response, without getting into delayed job or event machine? If those are the only option, I can deal with it, but it would make life simpler not to have to.

Here's what I have now:

```
remoteAddress = 'http://remote.server.address/'

params = {
  'a' => a,
  'b' => b }

url = URI.parse(remoteAddress)
Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643964/asynchronous-http-request-in-ruby

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate a [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) object before making the call, you can set its [read_timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-read_timeout-3D) attribute to a very small number, and then catch the resulting Timeout::Error exception and move on.

Here's an example that uses individual parts of the URL and query-string-formatted POST data:

```
endpoint = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
endpoint.read_timeout = 0.001
endpoint.post(path, params_as_query_string) rescue Timeout::Error
```